# Implementing PageObjects pattern for frames in a page

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, pageobjects

How to implement the pageObject pattern(Selenium) for frames in a page..I have a home page and there is a left frame and Right frame and i would like to create page object for each frame..

For example, I have the LeftFrame Page Object as below:

```
Public Class HomePageLeftFrame{

private WebElement link;
private WebElement textField;

}
```

How to write the @FindBy annotation for the two elements in the HomePageLeftFrame object...Is there a way?

**Note:** As per the documentation on the selenium for pageObjects it is mentioned that page objects can be a whole HTML page or part of a page..Is my understanding correct for the above implementation??

Comment: I think `linkinLeftFrame` and `textFieldLeftFrame` can be page objects too since they have other elements inside.

Answer (score 2):

Before writing my suggestion first I'd like to share my application for which I developed a POM framework. So basically my application has three different frames for each html page:

1. Top frame : It is shared view for whole application which contains common functionalists like Log-Out, help, Admin Settings etc.
2. Left navigation panel: At most of places in my application this frame is available and it provides navigation in between different section of application.
3. Content Frame: This is the frame where user does main operation.

To design a Page Object based framework for this type of application is really a tedious job, But I decided to design it in such a manner so that we can avoid all the repetitive code.First of all I'll share framework structure:

```
org.xyz.automation.sdk
     - TopFrame.java
     - MainNavigator.java
     - WebDriverFactory.java
     - Configuration.java
org.xyz.automation.sdk.global.pages
     - LoginPage.java
     - TopFrame.java
org.xyz.automation.sdk.global
     - Navigator.java
org.xyz.automation.sdk.leftpanel.pages
     - LeftFramePage.java
org.xyz.automation.sdk.leftpanel
     - LeftFrameNavigator.java
```

So basically `org.xyz.automation.sdk` contains all common configuration classes which has responsibility to instantiate web driver as per your system configuration.

`org.xyz.automation.sdk.global.pages`: This package contains page object class of common views, as I already said TopFrame is something which you can see throughout whole application so I modeled this view in `TopFrame.java`.To segregate the frame navigation from Page object class, I kept that in a separate package which is nothing but parent package of Page Object class.

`org.xyz.automation.sdk.global` contains `Navigation.java` which takes care of frame navigation and all other navigations. The only benefit of keeping it out from `global.pages` is that in future when your application won't support frames, you do not need to change any thing Page class, modify only navigator class.

`org.xyz.automation.sdk.leftpanel.pages`: Similar to above this package contains page object java class of left panel and again I separated out navigation of this left panel from `leftpanel.pages` package.

**@FindBy**
This is nothing but a shortcut way to find web-elements of modeled page. The very basic concept of page object is each class should model a single view only so modeled class should contain only those web-elements which actually appear on modeled view. For e.g.  `TopFrame.java` should contain log out element as it appears on that frame only.

```
    @FindBy(name = "logOut") // To find the element by name
    @CacheLookup
    private WebElement logOutLInk;
```

and while performing any action on it you should treat it as an instance of `WebElement`.

`logOutLInk.click();`

```
  /**
   * Class which models the view of Left Navigation Frame
   */
    public class LeftNavigationFrame{

        @FindBy(name= "exampleName")
        private WebElement exampleButton;

        private WebDriver driver;

        public LeftNavigationFrame(WebDriver driver) {
            this.driver = driver;
        }

        /**
         * Opens a new page by clicking example button
         */
        public void openNewPage() {
            exampleButton.click();
    }
}
```

Example of Navigator class:

```
  /**
   * Class which provides convenient methods to navigate on left frame
   */
    public class LeftFrameNavigator{
        private WebDriver driver;

        public LeftFrameNavigator(WebDriver driver) {
            this.driver = driver;
        }

        /**
         * Changes scope to the left frame 
         *
         * @return Page Object class of LeftNavigationFrame
         */
        public LeftNavigationFrame switchToLeftFrame() {
            // Code to switch Frame
            return new LeftNavigationFrame(driver);
    }
}
```

This is an example of your test class:

```
      /**
       * Class which contains test cases of xyz
       */
        public class doTesting{
        LeftFrameNavigator leftNav;

            @BeforeTest
            public void instantiateRequiredClasses() {
            LeftFrameNavigator leftNav = new LeftFrameNavigator();
            }

            @Test
            public void doTestingHere() {
            LeftNavigationFrame leftFrame = leftNav.switchToLeftFrame();
            leftFrame.openNewPage()
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: priyanshu, Thanks for your detailed answer & time. Can you please show me how you are initializing elements in `LeftFramePage` also can you give me some insight into class `LeftFrameNavigator`? I am still not clear on how to proceed for my project..Any code you can show is highly appreciated..Thank you so much..

Comment: @javanoob Added examples of required classes.

Comment: Thank you so much for the code..Now i got an idea on how to proceed with this..Once again thanks