# Selenium Webdriver: Java: Span Web Element Identification

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

I am using selenium webdriver and I am trying to find a text Box for a span tag but am having no luck. I was able to find a simliar text box for a div id so I am guessing it has something to do being a Span ID. Using the xpath I am generating this:

```
.//*[@id='rtbPrefix']
```

Therefore here is my WebElement I created:

```
@FindBy(xpath=".//*[@id='rtbPrefix']")
WebElement txtPrefix_AddContact;
```

please advise how I can find this item and if I should be using css instead and if so please advise me how i can find the element. Here is the info for the element below:

```
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td class="ContactLeftLabelCol">
<td class="ContactLeftInputCol">
<span id="rtbPrefix_wrapper" class="riSingle RadInput RadInput_Metro" style="width: 50px;" title="Enter the contact's title (Mr., Ms., Dr., etc. ">
<input id="rtbPrefix" class="riTextBox riEnabled riHover" type="text" value="" title="Enter the contact's title (Mr., Ms., Dr., etc. " size="20" name="rtbPrefix"/>
<input id="rtbPrefix_ClientState" type="hidden" name="rtbPrefix_ClientState" autocomplete="off" value="{"enabled":true,"emptyMessage":"","validationText":"","valueAsString":"","lastSetTextBoxValue":""}"/>
</span>
</td>
</tr>
```

Updates made per instructions given below

```
    @FindBy(xpath = "//frame[.//input[@id = 'rtbPrefix']]")
        WebElement iframe_Contacts; 

public void Add_Prefix_NewContact(){

        iframe_Contacts.sendKeys("Mr.");
        //txtPrefix_AddContact.sendKeys("Mr.");
    }
```

Updated webelemnt per instruction from reply, and then below is where it's implemented in my method

```
public void CreateANewContact(){
    NewContactClick();

    base.getDriver().switchTo().frame(iframe_Contacts);
    Add_Prefix_NewContact();
    Add_FirstName_NewContact();
    Add_MiddleName_NewContact();
    Add_LastName_NewContact();
    Add_Suffix_NewContact();
    Add_Primary_NewContact();
    Add_JobTitle_NewContact();
    Add_Email_NewContact();
    Add_Phone_NewContact();
    Add_Mobile_NewContact();
    Add_Fax_NewContact();
    Add_Address_NewContact();
    Add_Country_NewContact();
    Add_Zip_NewContact();
    Add_City_NewContact();
    Add_State_NewContact();
    btnSaveClose_AddContact.click();
    Reporter.log("A New Contact Was Successfully Added!!!");
    base.getDriver().switchTo().defaultContent();
}
```

Comment: Is the element inside an iframe?

Comment: Yes it is in an iframe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Yes it is in an iframe

You have to *switch into the frame's context* and then search for the element inside:

```
driver.switchTo().frame("name_or_id");

WebElement webElement = driver.findElement(By.id("rtbPrefix"));
```

If there is no `id` or `name` defined on the frame, you can either locate it by index:

```
driver.switchTo().frame(0);  // switch to the first frame
```

Or, locate it using `findElement`:

```
WebElement frame = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//frame[.//input[@id = 'rtbPrefix']]");
driver.switchTo().frame(frame);
```

Comment: Forgive my ignorance but if I am doing this from a Pagefactory format how would this be handled                                                                                           @FindBy(xpath=".//*[@id='rtbPrefix']")
    WebElement txtPrefix_AddContact;

Comment: @AndyWilliams cannot talk from experience, but this looks related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25736172/implementing-pageobjects-pattern-for-frames-in-a-page.

Comment: Where do i get the name of the iframe? i only see that it is an iframe from using firebug

Comment: Thank you for the detailed input however this still returned the no such element exception. I've switched over the the iframe window too  (see code above i added in)

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
WebDriver driver;
WebElement webElement = driver.findElement(By.id("rtbPrefix_wrapper"));
```